# Is it true for concave functions?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a function $f(\textbf{x})$ which is a concave function, ($\textbf{x}$ is a two element vector whose entities can take any value from the real line). I think since $\log(x)$ is a concave function therefore $\log(f(\textbf{x}))$ should be a concave function too. Is my reasoning right or wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\log(f(\textbf{x}))$ is defined only if $f(\textbf{x})>0$. But a concave function can't be positive in all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (unless it's a constant).

Comment: @ProfessorVector can we take an argument by restrictions?

Comment: It is not enough that $\log$ is concave; it is the fact that $\log$ is concave and _increasing_ that makes this so.

Comment: @ProfessorVector in a convex optimization context, it is assumed that $\log(f(x))$ enforces a domain constraint that $f(x)>0$; that is, $$\mathop{\textrm{dom}} \log(f(x)) = \{x\in\mathop{\textrm{dom}} f\,|\,f(x)>0\}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is defined on a convex domain, and $f(\mathbf{x}) > 0$ for all $\mathbf{x}$ in that domain, then the answer is yes.

In fact, it is a result of a well-known theorem: for any concave functions $f, g$, provided that the composition $h(\mathbf{x}) = g(f(\mathbf{x}))$ is defined on the domain of $f$, and $g$ is increasing on the range of $f$, the composition $h$ is also concave on the domain of $f$. In your case, $g \equiv \log$, which is indeed concave and increasing.

Comment: +1, and let me emphasize again that the _increasing_ (or, more generally, nondecreasing) nature of $\log$ is essential here. You can't just compose two arbitrary concave functions together.